# Can I build my own custom JavaScript app inside of the google sites?

Tags: google-sites

I have a requirement, where a client came with a concrete application with a few features. This is a small JavaScript application, which will require some logic implemented and interaction with a backend.
For example, think of a small online quiz, where admin can add questions and users can answer them. Answers are then saved in a database and can be compared with answers which were submitted there earlier. Questions are manageable by admin.

So since I am not familiar with a Google Sites much, I wonder: is it possible to build such an application and to integrate it into a Google Site? Probably will be a JavaScript code which be manipulating my custom created DOM. Have in mind that I also need to fetch a data. Is it feasible in this platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a form of any kind, Google Forms would be the best solution.

If you need to add custom HTML and JavaScript code, assuming you're using the new version of Google Sites:

- Add an Embed widget to a page on the Google Site. It is on the Insert tab.
- Choose Embed code.
- Add your HTML and JavaScript code here.
- Choose Next, then Insert.